# lim sup, lim inf, when sequence converges

Tags: real-analysis, limsup-and-liminf

I found this question online (not homework) and wanted to check my answer.

Let
$$A_1 = \{r: r \textit{ rational, and } \lim \text{inf } x_n <r < \lim \text{sup } x_n \}$$
$$A_2 = \{r: r \textit{ rational, and } \lim \text{inf } x_n >r\}$$
$$A_3 = \{r: r \textit{ rational, and } \lim \text{sup } x_n <r\}$$
State a simple condition involving the three sets above, that is equivalent to "$(x_n)$ converges to a finite value".

I believe that the answer is $A_1 \cup A_2 \cup A_3 = A_2 \cup A_3$, or simply that $A_1=\emptyset$.

My argument is that if $(x_n)\to p$, then $\lim \text{sup }=\lim \text{inf } = p$. Therefore set $A_1$ is empty, $A_2 = \{q\in\mathbb{Q}:q<p\}$ and $A_3 = \{q\in\mathbb{Q}:q>p\}$

Meanwhile, if $(x_n)$ does not converge, $A_1$ is not empty since $\lim \text{inf } < \lim \text{sup }$ and $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$.

Is my reasoning generally correct? Thank you very much.

Comment: This is mostly correct; the limit existing is indeed equivalent to $A_1 = \emptyset$. The only error is in claiming that this is equivalent to $A_1 \cup A_2 \cup A_3 = A_2 \cup A_3$. Generally speaking, if you know $A_1 \cup A_2 \cup A_3 = A_2 \cup A_3$, then all you can conclude is that $A_1 \subseteq A_2 \cup A_3$. Specifically speaking, $A_2 \cup A_3 = \Bbb{Q}$ for any sequence, so $A_1 \cup A_2 \cup A_3 = A_2 \cup A_3$ is true regardless of whether $(x_n)$ converges or not.

Comment: Hi, I don't see that $A_2 \cup A_3 = \mathbb{Q}$ if $(x_n)$ does not converge. Consider $x_n = (-1)^n$. Clearly $(x_n)$ does not converge, and we have $\lim \text{sup} = 1$ and $\lim \text{inf} = -1$. Then $A_2$ is rationals strictly less than -1, and $A_3$ is rational strictly greater than 1. In this case, $A_1 = (-1,1)\cap \mathbb{Q}$. 

In general, my logic was that for a non convergent sequence, $A_1$ represents rationals in between the lim sup and lim inf, while $A_2$ and $A_3$ are the rationals less and greater than the lim inf and lim sup, respectively. Am I missing something?

Comment: Further, I think the only case in which $A_1\subseteq A_2\cup A_3$ is when $A_1 =\emptyset$, just looking at the definitions of the sets. @TheoBendit

Comment: Yes, you're right. I somehow switched the inequalities in my head.

Comment: @TheoBendit thank you!